# merging dev branch to head with only one log message

Tags: git

Just say you have a development branch with 100 mostly pointless commit/log messages. Is it possible to merge the dev branch to the master/head and have only one log message in the master branch? ie one log message on the head/master branch might say "Adds features XYZ"

It seems there are two correct answers. Using squash allows you to hide all of the commits from the master branch, and using interactive rebase allows you to hide selected parts of the history from the master branch.

Comment: Although this is possible, consider whether you *really* want to lose all that history. The history can be useful later, such as when you're trying to track down the introduction of a bug.

Comment: Doh! So the way I understand it both answers are technically correct. Squash allows you to essentially hide all of the history, and rebase allows you to simply alter the history.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`git-merge --squash` followed by `git commit` should do this.

([More documentation on git-merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html))

Comment: I think this is the answer to my question, even if using the rebase option is probably a better thing to do.

Comment: I think one has to do `git commit` after that ?

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like [`git rebase --interactive`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) is what you need.  [This section](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html) of the Git Book explains:

> You can also rebase interactively.
>   This is often used to re-write your
>   own commit objects before pushing them
>   somewhere. It is an easy way to split,
>   merge or re-order commits before
>   sharing them with others. You can also
>   use it to clean up commits you've
>   pulled from someone when applying them
>   locally.

Comment: 'git rebase -i' is one of the greatest things I've ever learned.

Comment: Agreed. You don't want to squash (destroying history) if you can instead rewrite history to make it concise but still useful. Plus interactive rebases make you feel oh so powerful.